# SQL query execution time - SQL Server 2000 vs. SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am migrating a database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2014. For some reason a query with the following HAVING clause does not return any entries after more than an hour's execution time, while it returns all the results in less than a minute from the old server:

```
HAVING  (INOB.OBTAB = 'MARA') 
AND (isnumeric(LEFT(RIGHT(INOB.OBJEK, 10), 7)) = 1) 
AND (LEN(LEFT(RIGHT(INOB.OBJEK, 10), 7)) = 7) 
AND (KLAH.KLART = '023')
AND     (NOT (MVKE.LVORM = 'x'))
AND     (isnumeric(RIGHT(INOB.OBJEK,3)) = 1)
```

The culprit seems to be:

```
AND (LEN(LEFT(RIGHT(INOB.OBJEK, 10), 7)) = 7)
```

If I leave this condition out, the query returns results in about half a minute from the new server. My question is: Why? I don't see any computational hardship for the server in measuring the length of a string? And why would it differ between the two servers?

Thanks in advance for any pointers you might give me.

/Jens

Comment: Without any knowledge of the rest it is impossible to answer... You might try to use an  `APPLY` to get `INOB.OBJEK` as a real number, something like `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(INOB.OBJEK)=1 THEN CAST(INOB.OBJEK AS FittingNumberType) ELSE NULL END AS ObjekNum'  In the latter you can check for `ObjekNum IS NOT NULL AND ObjekNum<=9999999. Or you split your `OBJEK` in its parts and test them all typesafe...

Comment: The condition AND (LEN(LEFT(RIGHT(INOB.OBJEK, 10), 7)) = 7)  is equivalent to AND LEN(INOB.OBJEK) = 18 - and this does not return any response either. But if I change that to AND LEN(INOB.OBJEK) > 17 AND LEN(INOB.OBJEK) < 19, the query returns a response within a few seconds. How can that be? Are they not equivalent?